# Why org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat8

My web.xml code is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>rachelivf</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>main.do</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the code for dispatcher-servlet is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

    <mvc:resources location="/boardFile/**" mapping="C:/rachel/**"></mvc:resources>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property value="jsp/" name="prefix"/>
        <property value=".jsp" name="suffix"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="100000000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
            <property name="exceptionMappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException"></prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is the Tomcat server.xml configuration:

```
  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

  <Context docBase="rachelivf" path="/rachelivf" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:rachelivf"/>
  <Context docBase="C:/rachel" path="/boardFile/" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"/>
  </Host>
```

pom.xml code:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>rachelivf</groupId>
  <artifactId>rachelivf</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.38</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
         <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.8</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
         <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.2</version>
      </dependency> 

      <dependency>
         <groupId>jstl</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>       

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId> 
    <version>2.6.3</version> 
    </dependency>        

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-RC3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.sociaal</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlpull-xpp3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.20130526</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

These settings cause the following error:

```
경고: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.selectInvocableMethod(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
```

Is the setting wrong?

At first, the above error did not occur, No mapping error has occurred.
So I added
 `<mvc: annotation-driven>`

As a result, the above error has occurred.

No mapping This is the reason why the error occurred.
[How to upload files to Tomcat server path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432278/how-to-upload-files-to-tomcat-server-path)

Did I make the wrong setting? What does the program need to do to fix it?
Your comments are valuable. Help me.

Comment: Post the COMPLETE stack trace, including all "caused by" sections.

Comment: Do you need more information?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. @JimGarrison

Comment: There is definitely a problem with your dependencies in pom.xml. Can you try including `spring-aop` in your pom?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing different versions of spring dependencies in your pom.xml which don't work together.

The error `NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.selectInvocableMethod`
means that whoever is calling this method was likely compiled against a different version of `AopUtils` than in the runtime.

A quick search in maven central yields that `AopUtils::selectInvocableMethod` was added in `spring-aop` 4.3 versions. You only pasted an incomplete stack trace, the full one would contain a **caused by** section that highlights which class from another jar is calling it. However it's a good guess that  the culprit is in `spring-core`.

Running `mvn dependency:tree` on your pom.xml would yield the following list:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
```

`spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE` would want to use the method `AopUtils::selectInvocableMethod`, but it's not available in `spring-aop:4.1.6.RELEASE`. Make sure to not mix different versions of spring components, especially different major versions.

Also a lot of the listed dependencies would be included transitively, so the only ones you should list are:

- spring-webmvc
- spring-jdbc
- spring-oxm